# JAVASCRIPT Помогите пожалуйста с функцией и switch

Tags: javascript, функции, switch

```
    function func1(k,sk) {
         sk * k / 100 == summa
        return
    }
    
    var m = prompt("Сумма взятого кредита:");
    var t = prompt("Время вклада:");

    switch (t) {
        case 1:
            var b = 30
            break;
        case 2:
            b = 20
            break;
        case 3:
            b = 10
            break;
            
        case 6:
            b = 6
            break;
            
        case 12:
            b = 3
            break;
            
        default:
            alert("Данные неверны! ");



    }
    var a = func1(b, m);
    alert(a);
    //alert("Все работает");
```

Comment: В чем именно нужна помощь?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sk * k / 100 == summa
```

Вот здесь идет сравнение, а не присваивание. Так как summa не определена (исходя из приведенного кода), то это ошибка.
Для присваивания используем `=` и то ЧЕМУ присваиваем результат, пишем слева (так как выражения выполняются справа налево).

```
summa = sk * k / 100
```

Так как summa нигде больше не используется по функции, то результат вычислений можно сразу возвращать.

```
function func1(k,sk) {
   return sk * k / 100
}
```

Comment: спасибо большое